# What is the function of the human and no in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

a feral child is one who has had little or no **human** contact, thus she has **no** human language.

Comment: This question would get a better reception on ELL http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The "little or no" should be taken as a single phrase. 'None or almost none.'

"Human contact is simply contact with people. (They are not talking about contact with animals.)

In "has no human language" the word **no** describes the amount of human speech the feral child can manage.